# Get individual elements while matching a regex

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I have a certain string given like so..

`let string = "[@he man:user:123] [@super man:user:456] [@bat man:user:789]"`

Now, I need an array containing just the name and the id. For that, I applied the following regex..

```
extension String {
  func findMentionText2() -> [[String]] {
    let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(@\\w+(?: \\w+)*):user:(\\w+)", options: [])
    if let matches = regex?.matches(in: self, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) {
      return matches.map { match in
            return (1..<match.numberOfRanges).map {
                let rangeBounds = match.range(at: $0)
                guard let range = Range(rangeBounds, in: self) else {
                    return ""
                }
                return String(self[range])
            }
      }
   } else {
       return []
   }
 }
}
```

Now when I do `let hashString = string.findMentionText()` and print `hashString`, I get an array like so..

```
[["@he man", "123"], ["@super man", "456"], ["@bat man", "789"]]
```

So far so good..:)

Now I made a typealias and want to add it to an array..
 So I did this...

```
 typealias UserTag = (name: String, id: String)

  var userTagList = [UserTag]()
```

and then,

```
let hashString2 = string.findMentionText2()

for unit in hashString2 {
  let user: UserTag = (name: unit.first!, id: unit.last!)
  userTagList.append(user)

}

for value in userTagList {
    print(value.id)
    print(value.name)
  }
```

Now here, instead of giving `unit.first` and `unit.last` in `let user: UserTag = (name: unit.first!, id: unit.last!)`, want to add the `name` and `id` to the typealias as and when they are matched from the regex..ie.when I get the name or id, it should be added to the array instead of giving `unit.first` or `unit.last`..

How can I achieve that..?

Comment: Are you asking how to change your `findMentionText2` method to have a return type of `[UserTag]` instead of `[[String]]`?

Comment: yes @rmaddy..you are right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to refactor your `map` to generate an array of `UserTag` instead of an array of string arrays. Here's one approach:

```
typealias UserTag = (name: String, id: String)

extension String {
    func findMentionText2() -> [UserTag] {
        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(@\\w+(?: \\w+)*):user:(\\w+)", options: [])
        if let matches = regex?.matches(in: self, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) {
            return matches.compactMap { match in
                if match.numberOfRanges == 3 {
                    let name = String(self[Range(match.range(at: 1), in:self)!])
                    let id = String(self[Range(match.range(at: 2), in:self)!])
                    return UserTag(name: name, id: id)
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            }
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }
}

let string = "[@he man:user:123] [@super man:user:456] [@bat man:user:789]"
print(string.findMentionText2())
```

But I suggest you create a `struct` instead of using a tuple. It doesn't really change the implementation of `findMentionText2` but using a struct lets you add other properties and methods as needed.

Comment: When you print the array of UserTag, that's the output you get by default. It's the array of tuple that you wanted. You can whatever you want with the data in the array. You can use `map` and `filter` and anything else you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @rmaddy..but would u mind explaining in a couple of lines as to what u did exactly..I mean..like..why match.numberOfRanges == 3 is done or so..

Comment: Your regex has two capture groups. The first is the name and the second is the id, right? You wrote that so you should already know that part. Well a match will have those two capture groups plus one for the whole match. So that's why I added the check for 3 matches. It's there just incase to avoid crashes attempting to access the two desired ranges.

Comment: Ok @rmaddy..Thanks again…:)